# Filtering specific words from a string based on a words position in a text

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I have several part of speech rules and they are triggered only if the text being looked at matches the rule. However I'm curious if there is a way to remove "any" word that appears between a phrase that would otherwise trigger the rule. I tried using stop words, but it strips the text too much to where the rule becomes non-sensical. Heres an example.

```
Text: I want to attack this player's base.

attack_rule = [
                ('nn', 'i'),
                ('vbp', 'want'),
                ('to', 'to'),
                ('vb', ('exterminate', 'waste', 'attack', 'shoot'))
                ]
```

The text will trigger this rule, however if the text is written as such:

```
Text2: I f***ing want to attack this player's base.
Text2: I want to f***ing attack this player's base.
```

The rule won't trigger. So I'm wondering if there is a way to filter expletive/fillers from text that would otherwise trigger a rule? Ideally by position.

I'm currently using nltk's POS tagger. If there is a way to either make sure the word doesn't have a contextual effect on the sentence (like a superlative) which would seem way harder. Or just remove a word if it appears between text that would otherwise trigger a rule.

I tried using stop words but like I said it filtered far too much, especially when the object of the sentence was one of the most important parts.

```
He will attack all of them <- Stop words present
 he attack <- Filtered stop words
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your logic that checks if the POS tagged from the sentence matches your pattern looks like? feels like you could just keep ignoring a certain number of words with tags that don't match until the end of the sentence, and have a match if you found all the words with tags (in the correct order) you wanted in the end. You could also enforce a maximum number of consecutive words with bad tags in a row.

Also you could ignore words with only a few kinds of tags, like adverb or adjective

Comment: The check is based on a counter so, the pattern is in an ordered dictionary (via collections), for each matching POS tag the counter goes up, however if the target string is not in any of the specific orders of the rules the counter is reset. So if a rule has a k/v pair of length 3 the match has to be 3 in order for it to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency parsing to remove modifiers, as illustrated in the following code:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg', disable = ['ner'])

sentences = [ "I fucking want to attack this player's base." , "I want to fucking attack this player's base."]

for s in sentences:
    doc = nlp(s)
    print(s)
    print("=>", " ".join([t.text for t in doc if not t.dep_.endswith('mod') ]))

#I fucking want to attack this player's base.
#=> I want to attack this player 's base .
#I want to fucking attack this player's base.
#=> I want to attack this player 's base .
```